# How to add line in the circle canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have created a progress bar using css, javascript and html (left image).

But I want to add white colour divider in that progress bar like (right image). I have tried many ways but couldn't archive it. Can anyone help me to fix it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Aapn8/9923/)

[image]

```js
var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas

var options = {
    percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 45,
    size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
    lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 25,
    rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 200
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = el.getAttribute('data-text') + ' $';
    
if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

el.appendChild(span);
el.appendChild(canvas);

ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

//imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
  percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineCap = 'square'; // butt, round or square
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke();
};

drawCircle('#bbbec3', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
drawCircle('#c21b17', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
```

```css
.chart {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    text-align: center;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
span {
    color:#555;
    display:block;
    line-height:220px;
    text-align:center;
    width:220px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-left:5px;
} 
.centerbox{
        display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -50px;
    border-bottom: 35px solid #fff;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="graph" data-text="123123" data-percent="55"><label class="centerbox"><i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-top: 10px;position: absolute;"></i></label></div>
```

Comment: The javascript might be helpful. That is one way I am thinking it could be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the `globalCompositeOperation` we can draw these lines over the canvas and use them as a mask to clip the chart. The lines might need some adjustment to fit your needs, but the following should give you a jump start:

```
var drawMask = function(numberOfLines,clipLineWidth) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  // Revert the rotation already set:
  ctx.rotate( -1 * options.rotate * Math.PI / 180 );
  // This is where the magic happens:
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx.lineWidth =  clipLineWidth;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    ctx.rotate( Math.PI / (numberOfLines / 2) );
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 120);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  ctx.restore();
}
drawMask(8, 4);
```

To see how this plays along with your code see either [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwktx5sk/2/) or the following working sample:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas

var options = {
    percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 45,
    size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
    lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 25,
    rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 200
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = el.getAttribute('data-text') + ' $';
    
if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

el.appendChild(span);
el.appendChild(canvas);

ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

//imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
  percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineCap = 'square'; // butt, round or square
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
  ctx.stroke();
};

drawCircle('#bbbec3', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
drawCircle('#c21b17', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);

// Let's draw a mask over the chart:
var drawMask = function(numberOfLines,clipLineWidth) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  // Revert the rotation already set:
  ctx.rotate( -1 * options.rotate * Math.PI / 180 );
  // This is where the magic happens:
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  ctx.lineWidth =  clipLineWidth;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    ctx.rotate( Math.PI / (numberOfLines / 2) );
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 120);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  ctx.restore();
}
drawMask(8, 4);
```

```css
.chart {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    text-align: center;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
span {
    color:#555;
    display:block;
    line-height:220px;
    text-align:center;
    width:220px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-left:5px;
} 
.centerbox{
        display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -50px;
    border-bottom: 35px solid #fff;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="graph" data-text="123123" data-percent="55"><label class="centerbox"><i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-top: 10px;position: absolute;"></i></label></div>
```

Comment: Yeah the lines need some adjustment to fit. But this helped me out. Thank you so much. I marked as correct answer. Can you please help me this? https://jsfiddle.net/wwktx5sk/3/ I want to display two three chart. chart working with `ID` in javascript. Can you help me to do it in one javascript function for all chart.

Comment: First wrap (nearly) everything in a function called `createChart()`. Then create an array of all the charts on the page `var charts = document.querySelectorAll('.chart')` (I prefer using classes over IDs). Then loop over the array of charts and run `createChart` for each of them. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/wwktx5sk/4/). That being said, follow up questions like this - which is not directly related to the subject currently discussed - should be posted as separate questions :o)

Comment: this solution is not working on iOS mobile but working on Android and web. Can you help me to fix the issue? Why it's not supporting on iPhones :(

Comment: It's working for me on iOS 11. Could there be anything some else, like some of your CSS or javascript, messing with you? You can test the fiddle yourself at https://jsfiddle.net/wwktx5sk/2/show/

Comment: Thanks @agrm I will check it and appreciated your help.